Dual citizenship: Travelling with British and Turkish passports
I wonder if anyone can help me with some questions about using my 2 passports correctly.
My country of birth is Turkey but I live in the UK and I recently gained British citizenship - ie I now have dual citizenship, which is allowed by both countries.
What is the best way to travel between the UK and Turkey once I get my British passport?
I had imagined that I can just leave/enter the UK with my British passport and enter/leave Turkey with the Turkish passport… but a few things don’t make sense to me if I did this…

If I used my Turkish passport to enter Turkey, does that mean I must use the same passport to exit again?

If so, then that leads me to something I don’t understand…

Until now, in order to board a plane from Turkey to the UK, I have always had to show a valid visa for the UK at the exit passport control desk in Turkey. I obviously won’t have a UK visa to show anymore (as a UK citizen) so how would I show that I’m entitled to enter the UK, without showing my British passport in Turkey?

Also, in Turkey they stamp your passport when you leave/enter the country (even if you are a citizen), so if my passport hasn’t been subsequently stamped on entering/leaving the UK, are the Turkish authorities likely to ask any questions about that the next time I travel to Turkey?

If I decided to live, say one year in Turkey then the next year in the UK, does that change how I should use my passports? Obviously, as a citizen of both countries I have the right to reside longterm in either, but in terms of getting my passports stamped, would it cause any issues?


Thanks to anyone who is willing to try and help :)
